# How to mock objects for unit tests properly

Tags: c++, unit-testing, mocking

I find unit testing to be a great thing but I struggle with how to properly separate units of code. It was not immediately obvious but as soon as your unit test depend on another 'unit' of production code the maintainability of the tests and their benefits degrade rapidly. That is why we have mocks or stubs to achieve the separation of the 'unit' from everything else.

The way to do it is of course through interfaces. However I found that such approach impose rather harsh limits on what the interfaces can be. For example lets consider following class:

```
class Val
{
public:
    void set(int value) { m_Val = value; }
    void get() const { return m_Val; } 
private:
    int m_Val = 0;
};
```

All is good until you have another class that uses `Val`:

```
class SomeClass
{
public:
    void printValue(const Val &val) { std::cout << val.get(); }
};
```

Now in order to unit test `SomeClass` you should mock or stub `Val`. And there are only two ways to do it in C++ as far as I know:

1) Make `Val`'s methods virtual. Class `ValMock` then could inherit from `Val` and reimplement the methods to the test's needs. The problem is that you typically do not want to design your interface for unit tests. I find this rather invasive and the benefit of the tests in comparison to the costs (vtable lookups etc.) rather unconvincing.

2) Make mock implementation of `Val`. Separate source file that would compile (possibly in another library) and the test would link with that instead of the original. This approach however has costs too and no small ones at that. First of all you may not have inline definitions in your header because of the duplicit symbol definitions. And second if the implementation of the class you test is in the same library as the definition of the class you mock you will still get duplicit symbols. There is a way around this using pre-processor macros but I find it to be not very clean workaround.

Is there perhaps a third way? Or is any of the methods I have described the preferred one? Added value of tests is great but the design costs seem to me a lot higher than it seemed when I first started using them.

Comment: The third way is templatize your `SomeClass`. All 3 methods suck, and there is no good solution to this.

Comment: On the level of complexity of `Val` from your example I don't mock, but use the real class. After all you don't mock `int` or `std::string` in tests? But you will hit the same problem with more complex classes. I usually go for the usage of real implementation where possible, so my unit tests are more like "integration" tests. Works for *me* very well, but there're many people who dislike this approach. Also it probably depends a lot what you are developing, I *do* mock complex classes in tests where it makes sense and faking state of real implementation is bigger abuse/work than mocking it.